# The for-loop is not working

Tags: c#

The following code just shows `The ID Does Not Exist` as result.  What can be the problem?

```
int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
int n = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_noofrecomm.Text);
bool shart = false;
for (int yu = 0; yu <= 92161; yu++)
{
    int wer = d[yu];
    if (wer == sc)
    {
        shart = true;
        userseq = yu;
        var results = new List<float>(1143600);
        for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
        {
            results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
        }
        var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
        {
            sb1.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}: {1}", c[resultwithindex.Index], resultwithindex.result);
            sb1.AppendLine();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
    }
}
if (shart == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The ID Does Not Exist");
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through it.

Comment: How can we tell what is wrong when you are not showing us what d[] contains or how it may be loaded

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in `d[]` is equal to `sc`.

Comment: No @ Khanzor. when I remove the message it works correctly.the problem is with the message

Comment: really ? so when you remove the message it doesn't show the message? it's interesting

Comment: No i mean the result is correct and d[] is not empty @Selman22

Comment: Your predicate is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 2nd If-Statement, and then make the first if statement into an If-Else. 
Therefore you can effectively test your data in the future. You can then set shart to false, and then display messagebox.

```
    if (wer == sc)
{
    shart = true;
    userseq = yu;
    var results = new List<float>(1143600);
    for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
      {
        results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
      }
    var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
      {
        sb1.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}: {1}", c[resultwithindex.Index], resultwithindex.result);
        sb1.AppendLine();
      }
    MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
}else{
       shart = false;
       MessageBox.Show("The ID Does Not Exist");
}
```

Comment: Since you said the data is correct, and we can only see what you have given us. I assume since you said everything works when you remove the bottom if statement that your data is correct for d[] = sc.